# POS tag my own Corpus

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I have the following code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import TaggedCorpusReader

corpus_root = 'C:/Python27'
reader = TaggedCorpusReader(corpus_root, 'test.txt')
print reader.words()
print reader.tagged_words()
```

and the problem is that in the results give me value 'None' in each word..

```
[('And', 'None'), ('now', 'None')..
```

and when i have this code

```
import nltk
text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

the result is right...

```
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'), ('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

What is going wrong??

Comment: what is the content of `text.txt` ?

Comment: the content of test.txt is a text like an article

Comment: Should be like `word1/tag1 word2/tag2 word3/tag3 ...`

Comment: Now i undersatnd what you said..but i want to load my own file and then to pos-tagging it..do you know how can i do it?